# White space between divs and border of parent div

Tags: html, css

Whenever I add a border smaller than 5px to a parent div there is a bit of whitespace at the bottom and to the right of the content. As shown in the picture below.[The white space is visible here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woUuy.png)

Code Here:

```css
body {
  background: khaki;
  margin: 10px;
}

.nav>div {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}

.st-div {
  background: cadetblue;
}

.nd-div {
  background: crimson;
}

.rd-div {
  background: cadetblue;
}

.nav {
  border: solid 3px orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="st-div">Home</div>
    <div class="nd-div">About us</div>
    <div class="rd-div">Log Out</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i don't see it, what browser are you using?

Comment: I posted a photo. I am using the latest Chrome version.

Comment: The extra space is only visible when you zoom in on chrome, are you sure you are not zoomed in?

Comment: Just checked. I am not zoomed in.

Comment: There is space on my chrome, I am also on the latest version

Comment: Just to say, no space at firefox, full screen snippet, zooomed in or not.

Comment: @Huangism i cannot reproduce by zooming in, nor by try looking at the snippet fullscreen

Comment: Your posted image also seems bigger than what we see on the snippet, are there other styles involved with this?

Comment: @Giuppox Mac chrome

Comment: I am using Windows 10, The photo was just a cropped screenshot, I was not zoomed in.

Comment: @Huangism no other styles. This was just a test to help me learn Flexbox and I stumbled onto this problem.

Comment: Shouldn't you just put margin between the three divs?

Comment: I don't want margins between them. Just for them to fit the border fully.

Comment: @L4M3 ok sorry it seems no one here can reproduce the issue. I can only reproduce when zoomed in.

Comment: I'll look more into this. It's really bothering and I can only hope it's only my browser doing this.

Comment: I see the issue - it comes and goes depending on the amount of zoom (I am on Edge which is basically the same as Chrome on Windows10). The gap is not one whole CSS pixel, but part of one (e.g. 1 whole display pixel). I think it's quite a well known phenomenon due to rounding when a part CSS pixel is required in the arithmetic.

Comment: I don't see any problems. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCVyR.png

Comment: @AHaworth is there any known method that fixes or at least avoids this?

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 opening in Firefox or other browsers the problem disappears which is weird.

Comment: This problem is reproducible in Chrome Version 85.0.4183.121 (Official Build) (64-bit) at 100% zoom. (I'm also on Windows 10)